# Gradle tests fail locally, but succeed on CI servers

Tags: java, gradle, junit, continuous-integration

I have a Gradle Java project set up with JUnit unit testing. There are some tests that are supposed to fail. They do so on my machine, but it succeeds without errors on CI servers.

The natural first assumption is that something must be wrong with the CI server configuration. However, after not being able to get it to fail on CodeShip, I tried it with Travis and got the same result. In CodeShip, the peculiar thing is that the log told me that it simply did not find any tests (so of course there were no failed tests).

The test files are on the git repo (not ignored) and all scripts, be it Gradle or CI server configuration, are very simple. So I currently have no idea what is the issue here. For example, this is the .travis.yml:

```
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
```

And this is the `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'net.roughdesign.ajiwa'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

What could possibly cause this behaviour?

Comment: Are you sure the tests are really executed on CI? Maybe they are skipped for some reason. Why are you sure they have to fail on CI? Have you tried putting and `assertTrue(false)` into the tests to make sure they really fail? May be your test or application logic is time zone or locale dependent and therefore only fails on your machine but not on CI in the cloud.

Comment: @britter Yeah, all of that was fine, my mistake was mixing up the versions; I wrote an answer that explains it. Thank you for your effort nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was mixing up JUnit versions.

## JUnit 4

```
// in the Gradle file
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

// in Java code
import org.junit.Test;
```

## JUnit 5

```
// in the Gradle file
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'
testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1'

// in Java code
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

## What happened

- I imported both versions
- I wrote tests in JUnit 4 (using `import org.junit.Test;`)
- The CI servers use JUnit 5 as default

So there were indeed no *JUnit 5* tests.